# Get the issue with import external library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to import the library https://github.com/jpardogo/FlabbyListView

First, I download the Zip file, then I extract it then I copy it to the lib folder of my project, then I turn on my project in Android Stduio. I add this line in the build.gradle `compile 'com.jpardogo.flabbylistview:library:(latest version)'`. But the Android Studio show:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two concepts. If you use the `compile` dependency you don't have to put the jar in libs, and if you put the jar, don't put the managed dependency.

What the line `compile library:artifact:version` does is putting in your classpath in compile time the corresponding library, downloading it for you from a maven repository.

That said, I suggest you to remove the .jar and change your line of compile to:

`compile 'com.jpardogo.flabbylistview:library:1.0.0`

Comment: So that mean I only need to add this line in build.gradle
'compile 'com.jpardogo.flabbylistview:library:1.0.0'

Comment: Yes. Inside the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

if you are manually adding the library to android. then you will add it to you project also.
 In you `settings.gradle` file for the project add

```
include ':nameoflibrary'
```

or

```
include 'lib:nameoflibrary'
```

Where `lib` is the name of the folder you added the library and `nameoflibrary` is the actual name of the library.

then in you actual module usually the app-module gradle file add

```
dependencies {
compile project(':nameoflibrary')
}
```

or

```
dependencies {
compile project('lib:nameoflibrary')
}
```

same analogy too.

But if you are adding it from the repository you only need to add this line of code in your app-module gradle

```
dependencies {

 compile 'com.jpardogo.flabbylistview:library:(latest version)'
```

}

Comment: if you are using  `compile 'com.jpardogo.flabbylistview:library:(latest version)` then you don't have to manually add. once you have done that, you need to click `SyncNow` , to synchronize the library with your gradle. then the `import butterknife.ButterKnife` should not show red lines. or you can just rebuild you project from the `Build` Menu bar